# PayPal ignores subscription "notify_url" and uses profile endpoint instead for instant payment notifications (IPN)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

It seems PayPal started ignoring dynamically configured subscription "notify_url" and uses only IPN endpoint configured in profile for all newly created subscription since couple of days.

Seems to be still mentioned in documentation here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNSetup/#dynamically-setting-the-notification-url

My current use case is:

- 1st endpoint for non-recurring / one-time payments (configured via "notify_url")
- 2nd endpoint for recurring payments (configured via "notify_url")
- 3rd fallback/logging endpoint (configured in profile settings)

Is anyone else experiencing such issues, at the moment? Thanks!

Comment: Correctly specified values will be used. Incorrectly specified values will be ignored. You don't offer any example, so the latter is probably the case.

Comment: Thank you @PrestonPHX - here is an [example request](https://pastebin.com/Vpa8dk3x). Interestingly it worked for couple of years and stopped just recently (no change on my side).